# Iterate elements using ng-repeat in two diff structure

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

i have a code in which i want to iterate element inside two differnet row. 
Is it Possible to do it using single ng-repeat because i need the above row column structure to be fixed.only content should be dynamic ?

```html
<div class="row sortable">
   <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="row">
         <div class="col-md-12" ng-repeat="graph in graphs" ng-if="$even">
            <div> content.....</div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="row">
         <div class="col-md-12" ng-repeat="graph in graphs" ng-if="$odd">
            <div> content.....</div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just set the `ng-repeat` as a parent of your `rows` as follow:

```
<div class="row sortable">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="col-md-12" ng-repeat="graph in graphs">
            <div class="row" ng-if="$even">
                <div> content.....</div>
             </div>
             <div class="row" ng-if="$odd">
                <div> content.....</div>
             </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**UPDATE**

If you don't want to repeat the `<div class="row>`, you can create an `HTML template` and use two `ng-include` with different controllers on the HTML parent. I created a [Plunker example](http://plnkr.co/edit/d1742uAcjeWwnfMAKwOg?p=preview):

Parent HTML:

```
<body ng-app="includeExample">
  <div ng-controller="ExampleController">
    <div ng-controller="TemplateController1">
      <div ng-include="template"></div>
    </div>
    <div ng-controller="TemplateController2">
      <div ng-include="template"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

JS File:

```
(function(angular) {
  'use strict';
angular.module('includeExample', ['ngAnimate'])
  .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.template = "template1.html";
  }])
  .controller('TemplateController1', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.foo = "bar";
  }])
  .controller('TemplateController2', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.foo = "test";
  }]);
})(window.angular);
```

Template:

```
{{foo}}
```

Comment: that we can do but i dont want to repeat <div class="row"> .i just wat to repeat content inside div with class=row.

Comment: Thats correct but i want to do it in ng-repeat way ..like some div i can put in ng-repeat loop which do not iterate with every element